# Embed HTML5 Audio Player with M3U format

Tags: ios, html, audio

I am trying to embed a live radio stream in M3U format. After reading a bit it's come to my understanding that M3U at this point can't be embedded with HTML5. Is this true? If so how can I go about embedding that stream in a web page. The targeted platform is iOS so it can't be a Flash player.

Any suggestions? Can someone maybe recommend a JS player or something?

Comment: looks like apple disabled m3u's and pls's after ios 5.1.1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454722/apple-removed-the-possibility-to-stream-shoutcast-icecast-on-ios-6